# Ubuntu SPDIF input not working

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, spdif

I bought this [product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093L6SCG) , The problem is the SPDIF input not working

```
Linux 4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 10:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**$ lspci | grep -i audio**

```
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
03:01.0 Audio device: Creative Labs SB X-Fi
04:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The line in port is typically analog. I don't see the SB X-Fi
 SPDIF port listed in your input devices. Can you select it from the drop down menu?

Comment: @ElderGeek There is only `Line In` and `Microphone` in the drop down port menu under `SB X-Fi SPDIF ` device.

Comment: Related info: https://wiki.debian.org/X-Fi#Configuration  possibly useful

Answer (score 0):

What are you sending into your SPDIF input ? i ask this because there are subtypes and varients of SPDIF and you will need to match them up.

You can send a single PCM stream or an encoded bitstream , the soundcard will almost certainly not autodetect this and needs to be told what to expect.

There is also consumer and pro spdif , which can both be called SPDIF but are actually AES3.
http://www.sweetwater.com/insync/pro-consumer-s-pdif-standards-explained/

This thread suggests that SPDIF in is not likely to work on these cards under linux - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1655003

Professional grade audio cards can be cheaply bought on ebay and they will offer better spdif support and more active development than creative labs ones. Edirol , M Audio and Echo all make excellent soundcards that work with linux really well.